# Android notification's names on settings like facebook

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, application-settings

I would like to make users able to disable/enable notifications separately by their functionalities from settings app like Facebook or other applications do.

As image, Facebook shows a title for each notification use case (as you can understand from my terrible English I'm Italian, so screenshot is in Italian too), so users can disable or enable notifications depending on his need.

How can I do it? Can you post me a code example?
Thank you very much and tell me if I wasn't clear

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Have you researched creating notifications on Android?

Comment: @SammyT Yes, I searched about and I use notifications with Firebase, I should post some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create Notification Channels. Here’s a Util method I’ve created for that purpose:

```
public void createChannel(String channelId, CharSequence channelName, int importance) {
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, importance);
    channel.enableLights(true);
    channel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
    channel.enableVibration(true);
    channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}
```

where `channel` and `notificationManager`:

```
private NotificationChannel channel;
private NotificationManager notificationManager;
```

Just name the channels using the `channelId` and give them a description using `channelName`

Here's the Javadoc for the `NotificationChannel`:

```
/**
     * Creates a notification channel.
     *
     * @param id The id of the channel. Must be unique per package. The value may be truncated if
     *           it is too long.
     * @param name The user visible name of the channel. You can rename this channel when the system
     *             locale changes by listening for the {@link Intent#ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED}
     *             broadcast. The recommended maximum length is 40 characters; the value may be
     *             truncated if it is too long.
     * @param importance The importance of the channel. This controls how interruptive notifications
     *                   posted to this channel are.
     */
    public NotificationChannel(String id, CharSequence name, @Importance int importance) {
        this.mId = getTrimmedString(id);
        this.mName = name != null ? getTrimmedString(name.toString()) : null;
        this.mImportance = importance;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! I used channels, but did nothing... Where I have to create channels? I do it on a service that extends firebase... I must set up channels on MainActivity instead?

Comment: @geggiamarti I usually set them up on the application class

Comment: So I have to create a class that extends Application instead of an Activity?

Comment: @geggiamarti yes, if you want to guarantee that this is going to be the first thing that runs when your app launches.

Comment: Nice! I created channels in Application then I got notificationManager in my service for show the notification to the user, and my app's notification settings is showing all channels! Thank you very much!

Comment: @geggiamarti You're welcome, I'm glad you managed to make it work!